# Facebook SDK add image in content

Tags: php, facebook, image, sdk

I'm using this little good snippet to add content on a FB page and everything works fine ;))
http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/02/post-to-facebook-page-wall-using-php-graph

But how can I add an image (not a link) **below the content** ?

I tried with this but it does not work !

```
        'picture' => 'http://www.mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg',
        // or
        'source' => 'http://www.mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg',
```

Thanks for your help...

Chris

Comment: have you tried appending the image url to the 'message' field ?

Comment: Yes Amine but it stay as a link ;((

Comment: note sure here but maybe if you use the realpath of the image instead of the web path